# How to set private key and environment variables on PuTTY command line

Tags: ssh, cmd, putty

I want to include in my tunnel command line in Windows an additional option which will get private key. For example now the command is:

```
C:\putty.exe -ssh user1@localhost:2225 -pw pass1 -C -L 3395:127.0.0.1:3389
```

Server localhost is configured to use private key authentication file. What option to use in that case to use the file, I saw there is option `-i file.ppk`, but how to include that file from Windows dirrectory, for example:
`D:\file.ppk`.

Also is there any possible way to add environment variables they can be added from PuTTY settings *Connection=>Data*? But I want to put them in the command line, I have two variables with their values for example:

```
var: TARGET_SERVER val: 192.168.2.2 
var: TARGET_USER   val: user2
```

Comment: Your question would better fit to [su]. It's not really [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Just use a full path to the key on command-line. Make sure you enclose the path to double-quotes, if it contains spaces.

  ```
  C:\putty.exe -ssh user1@localhost:2225 -i "D:\path with space\file.ppk"
  ```
- No, there's no option to configure remote environment variables on command-line. But you can create a stored session in Windows registry and invoke it from the command-line.